# Connect MobileFirst Application with sql database

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have made new application Mobilefirst 8.0 using CLI.

I have followed [Link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/javascript-adapters/js-sql-adapter/#click-for-adapter-xml-attributes-and-subelements) to create sql adapter.

Added SQL databse file in root folder of project (root folder/Utils) is this right coz in 7.1 we have to add sql file under server folder.

Also added jdbc lib file in root folder. But when I trying to invoke adapter I am getting "**Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: getAccountTransactions2 in adapter: SampleAdapter SQL connection creation failed**" in logs.

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong. Below is my code uploaded in drive.

[Code here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxxy3QpD2PD3bHlhOW9LNmtIT0U)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I see what you did... you got it all wrong. You cannot include a "database file" in the application and expect the adapter to "connect" to this database.

Here is a diagram:

[application] ----> [mobilefirst server][adapter] ---> [database].

The application sends a request to the server to call the adapter which will send a request to the database, and then the response propagates back until it reaches the application, which send the original request.

You need to run your database in an actual server, not in the application.

---

> Added SQL databse file in root folder of project (root folder/Utils) is this right coz in 7.1 we have to add sql file under server folder.

I assume you are referring to the connector driver... This is wrong.
In v8.0 you add the connector as a Maven dependency in the adapter's **pom.xml** file.

Learn about maven dependencies:

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/#dependencies
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Depending on your database type, search for a connector in the maven repository site: http://search.maven.org/

Once you found it, add its reference to the pom.xml file and re-build your adapter.

Be sure though to add the correct values for your database, in the **adapter.xml** file (URL to database, username, password, ...).

For example for MySQL:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.mfp</groupId>
        <artifactId>adapter-maven-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>[8.0.0,9.0.0)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**adapter.xml**

```
...
...
<dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mobilefirst_training</url>
    <user>mobilefirst</user>
    <password>mobilefirst</password>
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

Comment: please refer my code.. in that SampleAdapter which I have created. I have already added dependencies in Pom.xml.. please refer my code I have already given you a link.

Comment: Oh okz. So what I did configuration in application and adapter part is right only database running part in wrong? Is that what you want to say?

Comment: So can you please please tell me how to run a database in actual development mobilefirst server?

Comment: Simply install MySQL community edition software on your computer. That's it.

Comment: Ok thats it. And add database in it and just put URL, username/password in pom.xml of maven project right?

Comment: No, the URL and username/password you put in the adapter.xml. Please read the tutorial.

Comment: Ok the url which is already there is right. Just have to add database and run it in MySQL.

Comment: still i am getting "SQL connection creation failed" Now I created database in MySQL and started MySQL server also. What causing this error?

Comment: Likely your MySQL connector.

Comment: Thanx its working now. But when i changed localhost with Ip address its giving "SQL connection creation failed" error. Why so?